# why don't document types created through umbraco admin get created as .cs files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, umbraco

New to umbraco.  Have umbraco project in VS2010 through which I run the umbraco admin locally.  When creating templates through the admin, the new template appears as a master page in my Masterpages directory.  Why is it that when I create a new document type through the admin, those do not appear as .cs pages in the DocumentTypes directory like I see them existing in projects that have already been created?  Hate feeling like such a noob...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Document types are stored as database structures, and are *not* classes - even though they behave as such with property inheritance.
To get a strongly-typed document type as a CS file for use in your code, though, you can right-click any document type and select "Export to .NET", which lets you save a CS file to your hard disk which you can then use in Visual Studio.

Edit: Another resource that you may find useful is http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/linq-to-umbraco/generating-classes-from-document-types - which explains how you can source-control some aspects of your document types using the LINQ2Umbraco library. However, as with all CMS systems, the safest methods fro preserving both structure and content are a) saving your genscripts for your DB to your source control system, b) backing up the DB and saving the BAK file into source control, or c) look at RedGate SQL Source Contol for a professional tool for source-controlling your database.

Comment: Oh, that's great.  To follow up with two other questions: 1) If I make changes to the cs files, is umbraco's admin aware of them or is it strictly looking at the structures in the db?  2)  Is what you stated for document types different from templates?  I ask because I noticed that when you make changes to the .master files and Reload Nodes in the umbraco admin, that it picks up those changes, so don't know in what ways templates are handled differently from document types by umbraco.  Thanks again!

Comment: 1) No, Umbraco will not pick up the CS changes - it looks at the document types as they are stored in the DB. To update your CS, add new properties to the doctypes, then re-"Export to .NET"; 2) Yes - templates are simply classic ASP.NET master pages as stored on disk under the /masterpages directory, so you can update on disk and see the changes in the CMS interface, and vice versa.

Comment: -1 (no I didn't actually down vote. The post is a good depiction of the reality.) But it's not an ideal situation. It's not difficult to come up with some initialisation module that creates document types based on some certain classes. I certainly can easily do it if I weren't writing a CMS myself (cos you know, there's not enough CMS' around).

Comment: @SleeperSmith yes, it's not ideal, however you can use uMapper (http://ucomponents.org/umapper/) for mapping POCO objects to document types (similar to how you would map interfaces to concrete types in Structuremap), or you can use uSiteBuilder (http://usitebuilder.vegaitsourcing.rs/) to generate document types from POCOs with attribute decoration. I'm personally not a fan of uSiteBuilder, as the last time I used it, it had sync problems when N+1 devs are working on a single DB, but YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Templates (masterpages) are different to doc types - a single doc type can be rendered in many different ways by being assigned to many different templates/masterpages.

Umbraco creates some things physically and some things virtually - templates (masterpages), media (images), usercontrols, macroscripts (.cshtml razor scripts), stylesheets and scripts (.js files) are created as physical things in your file structure even when generated using the umbraco admin.  Most of the rest of the site is created virtually in the database or cached into \app_data\umbraco.config and can't easily be created outside of the umbraco admin area.